# How can I use stdout to update information?

Tags: python, terminal, stdout

I have a script that runs every minute until midnight.  I want it to update the command line on its progress as it works.  I want the script to update me on how many calculations it did this cycle, how many it will do next cycle, and how long until the next cycle.  Here is my code:

```
import datetime
import time
import sys
from crawler import crawler

seconds_for_sleep = 60

total_x = 0
total_y = 0


t = datetime.datetime.now()

while t < datetime.datetime( t.year, t.month, t.day+1,0,0,0,0):



    x, y = crawler()

    total_x +=x
    total_y +=y

    sys.stdout.write("\r")
    sys.stdout.write("{:2d} calculations made in total.".format(total_x) )
    sys.stdout.write("{:2d} calculations next cycle.".format(total_y) )
    sys.stdout.flush()



    for remaining in range(seconds_for_sleep, 0, -1):
        sys.stdout.write("\r")
        sys.stdout.write("{:2d} seconds remaining.".format(remaining)) 
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)

    sys.stdout.write("\rStarting Next Round!            \n")
```

The desired output after one cycle should be

```
10 calculations in total
6 calculations  next cycle
```

and then it should update without print a new line to

```
16 calculations in made in total
 3 calculations next cycle
```

However, as I have written the script, it does not do this.  It instead just clears the same line over and over.  How can I use `stdout` to accomplish what I want?

Comment: it should do what you want. Are you piping the output through `less` or something? Are you on a terminal: what does `stty -a` say?

Comment: I am running the script in terminal.  `stty -a` gives me an error, saying that the name is not defined.

Comment: You're printing two lines. Now, `\r` will return to the begin of the line, but to actually do a reverse line feed you will need to use some escape code proper to your type of terminal, like `<ESC>[1A` on a terminal that understands VT100 escape codes (by the way that code is also supported under ANSI, so it's among the more portable ones).

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Mac OSX 10.10